# (Qt C++) Write QString to file as Binary

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, binary, hex

I am working on a project and I need to write (and in the future read) a string (QString) as binary. The string is in HEX format, like this "00010203040506070a0f01" etc...

I got this far through a tutorial on YouTube:

```
void Output()
{
    QString ye("01020a");
    QFile file("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Qt_Projects\\myfile.dat";

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open file to be written";
        return;
    }

    QDataStream out(&file);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);

    out << ye;

    file.flush();
    file.close();
   }
```

But when I open "myfile.dat" with a hex editor, the hex values are different, the QString "ye" was written to the text side of things.

```
00 00 00 0C 00 30 00 31 00 30 00 32 00 30 00 61
```

Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should convert it before writing.

```
QByteArray array = QByteArray::fromHex(ye.toLatin1());
file.write(array);
```

You don't need to use `QDataStream` since you already have `QByteArray` and can write it directly.

You can read and convert the data back to hex representation as follows:

```
QString s = file.readAll().toHex();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thx   I need to wait 4 min before accepting

Comment: Just wondering, how would I go about reading a file to a QString? I'm assuming a variation of this, but anything I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean converting it back to hex representation? `QString s = file.readAll().toHex();`

Comment: Perhaps, what is the easiest way to print the string? I'm very new to qt. Im messing with qDebug but I don't know where it displays

Comment: Yes it worked :) I foudn the App Output and everything is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

in QString each character occupy 2 bytes (Using unicode).
You can consult the ascii table to search a character's code value in hex int:

```
'0': 0x30
'1': 0x31
'a': 0x61
```

so for the string `"01020a"` its ascii code sequence is: `00 30 00 31 00 30 00 32 00 30 00 61`

`"00 00 00 0C":` I think it's the type identify for QString.

Sorry for my poor expression, hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Saving QString to QFile;

```
QString qStr="abc";
qFile.write(qStr.toUtf8().constData());

conversion sequences are here;
   QString => QByteArray => const char* => QFile.write()
```

[ref class function]

```
QByteArray QString::toUtf8() const;
const char * QByteArray::constData() const;
qint64 QIODevice::write(const char * data);
```